# white space around embed element when zooming browser

Tags: css, embed

I'm embedding NPR news in my webpage, but when zooming in (enlarging) the browser, white space appears around the embedded element. It seems that an embedded element has a white background and reacts to the zooming of the browser window. So I read in this link [How to get rid of white space around an <embed> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712459/how-to-get-rid-of-white-space-around-an-embed-element) an iframe could be a solution. Is that an acceptable way? Just give the src attribute link to the src attribute iframe solves the problem?

```
<embed src="http://www.npr.org/v2/?i=339878618&#38;m=339878619&#38;t=audio" height="386" wmode="opaque" allowfullscreen="true" width="400" base="http://www.npr.org" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove margin and padding from the embed element.

```
body{margin:0; padding:0; background:blue;}
embed{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/9922871h/4/

Comment: If you zoom in the browser window, white space expands around the embedded element. I'm wondering maybe if there's a way to keep the size of embed element as it is even when you enlarge the window.

Comment: Not sure how your html structure looks like. Could you post a jsfiddle or a link to your page?

Comment: You can see it on your demo too. Enlarge 110% and the white space shows up.